# How do I simulate keyboard events in Chromedriver/Selenium for Node.js?

Tags: node.js, selenium, selenium-chromedriver

I'm trying to automate uploading an image file to a server to which I don't have a better form of access (FTP, etc.). I'm using Node.js with Selenium and Chromedriver, and everything is going well until I need to simulate special keys. I've researched a bit, and have found nothing so far. Mac specific answers are ok for this.

I tried this from another answer somewhere, but it's not working for me:

```
driver.findElement(webdriver.By.name(uploadName))
        .click()
        .sendKeys(Keys.COMMAND + Keys.SHIFT + 'g')
        .sendKeys(imgPath)
        .sendKeys(Keys.RETURN);
```

It fails out because Keys is undefined, but I haven't run across any other ways to get at the commands.

Comment: What do you need the commands for?. Are you triying to paste the file path from the clipboard or something?

Comment: Specifically I need to sendKeys to the file open dialog. CMD+SHIFT+G opens the file path dialog so I can sendKeys of the filepath.

Answer (score 0):

After further research, it seems that this is the wrong way to do this. Selenium and Chromedriver don't really support OS level interaction, but there is an easier way.

```
driver.findElement(webdriver.By.name(uploadName)).sendKeys(imgPath);
```

This will target *uploadName* and then give it the file path passed into **sendKeys**. This bypasses the messy OS file dialogs.